# Pinch to zoom, double tap to zoom + swipe gestures

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

EDITED: NOW The entire class is posted, not just the inner custom listener

For a couple weeks now I kept this problem in my mind and still have no answer. I want to make a "Photo view activity" where the user is brought to see a photo on the entire screen. The users must be able to double tap to zoom, pinch to zoom and also to be able to exit the activity when they swipe left/right. For now I am able to do the following:
swipe to exit
pinch/double tap to zoom(Photo attacher)

However, if I try to use both at the same time the system will think that I am trying to zoom and won't trigger listeners for  swipes.Since the photo attacher is trivial, here is some code for the swipe part: A inner class

```
public class PhotoShowActivity extends Activity{
//  Toolbar bar;
PhotoView photoToShow;
PhotoViewAttacher attacher = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_show);
    //set up bar
   // bar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_with_back_key);
  //  bar.setTitle("");
    //setSupportActionBar(bar);
   // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  //  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    photoToShow = (PhotoView) findViewById(R.id.photo_show);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    try
    {
        File receive = (File) i.getSerializableExtra("image");
     //  getSupportActionBar().setTitle(i.getStringExtra("title"));
        Glide.with(this).load(receive).into(photoToShow);


    }catch(Exception e){finish();}
    attacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(photoToShow);
    photoToShow.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(PhotoShowActivity.this)
    {
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            PhotoShowActivity.this.finish();
        }
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
                    PhotoShowActivity.this.finish();
        }
        public void onSwipeTop() {
            //       PhotoShowActivity.this.finish();
        }
        public void onSwipeBottom() {
            //      PhotoShowActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });

}

public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (attacher.getScale() == 1.0) {
            gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                        result = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeTop();
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }
}
```

}

Here we have the listener being bind to the image view

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(PhotoShowActivity.this){
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            PhotoShowActivity.this.finish();
        }
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
                    PhotoShowActivity.this.finish();
        }
        public void onSwipeTop() {
            //       PhotoShowActivity.this.finish();
        }
        public void onSwipeBottom() {
            //      PhotoShowActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });
```

Any ideas on how I can combine zoom and swipes ?

Comment: For pinch to zoom which library you have used  for your ImageView?

Comment: There is a library available for that https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Comment: Where is your pinch to zoom and double tap to zoom methods? You say when you combine them is where your issue is, but you only provided the swipe function. Please provide how you combine them.

Comment: I use photo view and attacher. I bind the attacher then i use the presented listener. I can post the full code if needed anymore

Comment: @LucianComșa, I need the sample.

Comment: @LucianComșa let me know if this issue was resolved.I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @LucianComșa  Hi Could you please share how you resolved it ? I having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to check whether your ImageView is zoomed or not. If it is zoomed in then your swipe left and right functionality should not work. PhotoView library provides functionality to check zooming level of ImageView. I have faced the same issue and I have figured out. You can find below snippet for your reference,

```
   @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (imgPdfView.getCurrentZoom() == 1) {
            mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

If `imgPdfView.getCurrentZoom()==1`, It means your ImageView is in normal state. So now you can swipe left or swipe right for the further functionality.

Comment: I still can't figure it out.. I use the PhotoView, i changed the onTouch method to the one that you shown and for some reason it doesn't work. The gestures works but the zoom doesn't. I can't find the getCurrentZoom method so I use the getScale of the photoView. Good to mention that I use the PhotoViewAttacher for the zoom feature. Any ideas? I can provide the full code in the activity that shows the photo(as the one in the question is just the inner class) if necessary.